# Mustache/jQuery/javascript - how to perform method on mustache variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I have a simple mustache template setup that takes an object `player` and creates a list element. What's the best way to perform a javascript method on a variable in mustache? Here's some sample code:

```
var playerTemplate = '<li><span class="player-position">{{ position }}</span><span class="player-name">{{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}</span></li>';
var playerRow = Mustache.to_html(playerTemplate, player);
$('ul#players-list').append(playerRow);
```

what i'd like to do is something like:

```
{{ position.toUpperCase() }}
```

I'd rather not change the object itself, because i may want {{ position }} to not be upper case in other situations. Any tips on the cleanest smartest way to do this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mustache is intentionally very simple ("Logic-less templates") so there's not a lot you can do. One option is to add a `positionUC` property:

```
player.positionUC = player.position.toUpperCase();
```

and then in the template:

```
{{positionUC}}
```

You can also add functions:

```
// Note that render(text) will be HTML though...
player.uc = function(text, render) { return render(text).toUpperCase() };
```

and then in the template:

```
{{#uc}}{{position}}{{/uc}}
```

Perhaps you could switch to [Handlebars](http://www.handlebarsjs.com/) and add a helper to uppercase things.

Comment: Oh right, that's a good point about the logic-less-ness. Adding positionUC was quick and simple. went with that, thanks!