# How do i capitalize a variable in mustache

Tags: javascript, html, mustache, title-case

I have this variable in my mustache template called type, i want to capitalise the value of type using title case, is this possible ? taking into consideration that type is not what is displayed on the web page, it stores a value.

{{type}}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mustache/jQuery/javascript - how to perform method on mustache variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460720/mustache-jquery-javascript-how-to-perform-method-on-mustache-variable)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202159/how-to-use-jquery-built-in-functions-in-mustache-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a `span` and use CSS.

CSS

```
.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Template

```
<span class="capitalize">{{type}}</span>
```